# Match value of array from database object in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my first app project using Google Cloud Functions & Firebase.  I'm trying to find away to get a single value of the array that I'm returning and compare it to a set variable and if it matches, update another child's value in that same account.

My App users can add records to the database under their login/user_id that is stored in the database.  I'm trying to get a list of the "RecordName" that is a child under that login/user_id that every user has stored in their account.

So basically every "RecordName" in the entire database.  When I want to run specials for those records, I need to match the name of that record to the name of the record I have on special and if there is a match, update another child value under that user's account ("special" = true.). This way, when they load their app next time, I have it highlighting that record so they know it's on special.

When I use..

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(`/store`);
```

...with the following code...

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  // puts ALL items of the object into array using function  ..
   console.log(snapshotToArray(snapshot));
   });
```

... and the function...

```
function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
var returnArr = [];

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item = childSnapshot.val();
    item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    returnArr.push(item);
});

return returnArr;
};
```

... I get the entire array just as it is in the database:

```
-store
    -{ones_users_id}
        -recordname: value1
        -special: false
    -{anothers_users_id}
        -recordname: value2
        -special: false
```

ect. ect.

If my record on special is called, "Newbie Record", what would be the best way to take out every individual value for the key: "recordname" from the array, compare each one to var = "Newbie Record" and if they match, update the value of the key: "special" to be true?

I'm new to JSON and NodeJS, I've been searching on here for answers and can't find exactly what I'm looking for.  Your feedback would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to **query** your database for nodes that have `"recordname": "Newbie Record"` and update them.

An easy way to do this:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(`/store`);
const query = ref.orderByChild("recordname").equalTo("Newbie Record");
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.update({ special: true })
  });
});
```

Main differences with your code:

- We now use a query to read just the nodes that we want to modify.
- We now use `once()` to read the data only once.
- We loop over the children of the `snapshot`, since a query may result in multiple nodes.
- We use the reference of each child and then update its `special` property.

I recommend reading a bit more about [Firebase queries in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).